# Grayzone between blocking and non-blocking I/O?

Tags: multithreading, jvm, akka, blocking, nonblocking

I am familar with programming according to the two paradigms, blocking and non-blocking, on the JVM (Java/nio, Scala/Akka).
However, I see a kind of grayzone in between that confuses me.

Look at any non-blocking program of your choice: it is full of blocking statements!

For example, each assignment of a variable is a blocking operation that waits for CPU-registers and memory-reads to succeed.
Moreover, non-blocking programs even contain blocking statements that carry out computations on complex in-memory-collections, without violating the non-blocking paradigm.

In contrast to that, the non-blocking paradigm would clearly be violated if we would call some external web-service in a blocking way to receive its result.

But what is in between these extremes? What about reading/writing a tiny file, a local socket, or making an API-call to an embedded data storage engine (such as SQLite, RocksDb, etc.). Is it ok to do blocking reads/writes to these APIs? They usually give strong timing guarantees in practice (say << 1ms as long as the OS is not stalled), so there is almost no practical difference to pure in-memory-access. As a precise example: is calling RocksDBs get/put within an Akka Actor considered to be an inadvisable blocking I/O?

So, my question is whether there are rules of thumb or precise criteria that help me in deciding whether I may stick to a simple blocking statement in my non-blocking program, or whether I shall wrap such a statement into non-blocking boilerplate (framework-depending, e.g., outsourcing such calls to a separate thread-pool, nesting one step deeper in a Future or Monad, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

> for example, each assignment of a variable is a blocking operation that waits for CPU-registers and memory-reads to succeed

That's not really what is considered "blocking". Those operations are constant time, and that constant is very low (a few cycles in general) compared to the latency of any IO operations (anywhere between thousands and billions of cycles) - except for page faults due to swapped memory, but if those happen regularly you have a problem anyway.

And if we want to get all nitpicky, individual instructions do not fully block a CPU thread as modern CPUs can reorder instructions and execute ones that have no data dependencies out of order while waiting for memory/caches or other more expensive instructions to finish.

> Moreover, non-blocking programs even contain blocking statements that carry out computations on complex in-memory-collections, without violating the non-blocking paradigm.

Those are not considered as *blocking the CPU from doing work*. They should not even block user interactivity if they are correctly designed to present the results to the user when they are done without blocking the UI.

> Is it ok to do blocking reads/writes to these APIs?

That always depends on why you are using non-blocking approaches in the first place. What problem are you trying to solve? Maybe one API warrants a non-blocking approach while the other does not.
For example most file IO methods are nominally blocking, but writes without `fsync` can be very cheap, especially if you're not writing to spinning rust so it can be overkill to avoid those methods on your compute threadpool. On the other hand one usually does not want to block a thread in a fixed threadpool while waiting for a multi-second database query

Comment: Yep. Even non-I/O pure computation could be considered blocking in some circumstances, for example some crypto algorithms on large enough chunks of data. Memory allocation and deallocation usually is not considered blocking, but in realtime systems it may be. It depends.

Comment: @ephemient they might be blocking the application from doing something that is considered more important, they're certainly not blocking the CPU from doing work. different abstraction levels

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, the technical definition of "blocking" as "blocking the CPU from doing work" sounds unfamilar to me. For example, large "blocking" file-reads do not block the CPU neither, since the OS switches to another thread until the data transfer from hdd to memory has finished. AFAIK, in the context of JVM-based computational frameworks, "blocking vs. non-blocking" is usually meant to be equivalent to "synchronous vs. asynchronous control flow", on the abstraction level of language-statements.

Comment: Blocking IO *does* block the CPU from doing any further work *on the current thread of execution*. A context switch is only possible if there additional threads which can be scheduled in, which is not necessarily always the case. And *context switches are not free*, so one uses non-blocking IO where possible to also avoid the cost of context switches and thread stacks for 1-thread-per-blocking-OP. It's like the distinction between parallelism and concurrency, they are related but not the same.

Comment: You asked a very broad question. Maybe I misunderstood your intent due to imprecise language, but maybe you could clarify if you're seeking a different answer. But I think my last paragraph applies either way. Or maybe it's more suited to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/